# Run parallel process and exit all if one fails

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu

I have this snippet of code, to start `make t1` , `make t2` and `make t3` in parallel.

Is there a way to kill rest of the make processes when one fails? e.g, if `make t2` fails, script should kill other 2 running (`make t1` and `make t3`) and come out.

```
for ARG in '"t1" "t2" "t3"'
do
   cd ${ARG}
   make ${ARG} & pid=$!
   PID_LIST+=" $pid";
   cd -
done
trap "kill $PID_LIST" SIGINT
echo "Parallel makes have started $PID_LIST"
wait $PID_LIST
```

Comment: Why are you using `eval`? `for arg in "t1" "t2" "t3"; do make "$arg" & pids+=($!); done`

Comment: Thanks, will change it in my code as you suggested

Answer (score 2):

With **GNU Parallel**

```
parallel --halt now,fail=1 'cd {}; make {}' ::: t1 t2 t3
```

Comment: Thanks Mark, I updated my code snippet, I have to cd to different directory before `make`, so I cannot club `make`'s into one line.

Comment: @Krish You always change to the same directory in your code..., and you can do multiple commands with `parallel` anyway. I have updated the code.

Comment: That was a typo, please see now, dir names are different.