# Force parallel sub shells to exit main shell

Tags: shell, parallel-processing

I have the following shell script that runs parallel sets of serial commands, waits, then runs additional commands after everything is finished:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

good() {
  sleep 1
  echo $1 ok
}
bad() {
  sleep 1
  echo $1 bad
  exit 1
}

(good A1 ; good A2) &
(bad B1 ; good B2) &
wait

good C1
```

If something fails ("B1" in this example), I want everything to exit. But, when I execute it, it continues to run until the end.
The output I WANT is

```
A1 ok
B1 bad
```

But the output I get is:

```
A1 ok
B1 bad
A2 ok
C1 ok
```

Comment: Easy with **GNU Parallel**, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/43187508/2836621

Comment: @MarkSetchell, sorry but GNU Parallel is not available on the systems that I need to run this in, and I don't have administrative rights to install it.

Comment: Maybe have a read here... https://oletange.wordpress.com/2018/03/28/excuses-for-not-installing-gnu-parallel/

Comment: Thanks for @MarkSetchell for the parallel suggestion, and for ways to get around restrictions in my organization for installing it. I just don't feel comfortable going down that path.

Answer (score 0):

While I didn't find an exact solution, I adjusted my script to at least exit before C1 is executed, by writing exit codes to a shared file:

```
#!/bin/sh

set -e

o=$HOME/output
echo "" > $o # empty file

good() {
  sleep 1
  echo $1 ok
}
bad() {
  sleep 1
  echo $1 bad
  exit 1
}

( good A1 ; good A2 ; printf "$?" >> "$o") & # 0 if both A1 and A2 succeeded
( bad B1 ; good B2 ; printf "$?" >> "$o") & # 0 if both B1 and B2 succeeded
wait

if [ `cat $o` != "00" ]; then exit 1; fi # 00 means everything succeeded

good C1
```

This at least gives me something close to what I expected:

```
A1 ok
B1 bad
A2 ok
```

rather than

```
A1 ok
B1 bad
A2 ok
C1 ok
```